# How can i send the bulk sms through twilio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio

var notification = NotificationResource.Create(
            serviceSid,
            toBinding: new List { "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"+1651000000000\"}"}
            body: "Knok-Knok! This is your first Notify SMS");

my question is that how i will send the data in toBinding parameter.

Help me

Comment: This page has a C# code example (upper right corner), `Send a Notification to Bindings in the request` - https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notification-resource

Comment: Hello Alan actually i wanna know ,how to send list of contacts into tobinding parameter of Notification API?

Answer (score 0):

I use JS/Node (so sadly I don't have a C# example). I had success using the technique below. Maybe you can reverse engineer to your needs.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('Body', 'Hello from Node-Fetch!!!');
params.append('ToBinding', '{ "binding_type": "sms", "address": "+14075551212" }');
params.append('ToBinding', '{ "binding_type": "sms", "address": "+18025551212" }');

let headers = {Authorization: 'Basic ' + new Buffer.from(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN).toString("base64")};

console.log(`To String Output: ${params.toString()}`);

fetch('https://notify.twilio.com/v1/Services/IS076575aa3098c700a174ad0123456789/Notifications',
    {method: 'POST', headers: headers, body: params})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: actually i am  getting the following error while sending the request                                    
 (Can not convert incoming parameters to Notification object: Parameter 'ToBinding' is invalid)

Comment: how to achieve exact format like this in c#                                                                            "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"+91123456789\"}",
"{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"+91123456789\"}"

Comment: I don’t know, since I am not a C# developer, any one else have feedback?